# why is button not getting the color i am giving it?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am working on the site with bootstrap 4 and the button in the showcase is not getting the colour i am giving to it.

HTML

```
                <button  class="btn btn-primary  btn-lg text-white ">book me </button>
```

CSS

```
btn-primary {
    background: coral;
}
```

Comment: use !important. But you shouldn't be overriding bootstrap classes that way.

Comment: You can design your custom class as well to get a button background to be changed.

Comment: You made a typo. Class selectors begin with a `.` which you forgot.

Answer (score 1):

Provide more specific classes or use !important.

```css
.btn-primary.btn-lg.text-white {
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <!-- our css  -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./app.css">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,300,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Aurora Grove</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section id="showcase">
    <div class="header container text-white d-flex d-flex align-items-center  flex-column py-4 border hight-showcase justify-content-center">
      <button class="btn btn-primary  btn-lg text-white ">book me </button>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```